# Email received in spam gmail

Tags: outlook, gmail, spam, spf, dkim

My mail is passed  with SPF,DKIM,DMARC and RDNS.I checked blacklist using mxtoolbox, it is not blacklisted but still my mails are going spam in gmail,outlook.Please give any suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This is really too broad a subject for Stack Overflow. Setting all of those provides no guarantee of inbox placement. Spam filters are entirely arbitrary and unstandardised. Those things *can* help, but you have no way of knowing. It's also highly dependent on your content and what your recipients do with your messages. Many large ISPs assume everthing is spam unless told otherwise.